# How to pair-wise compare two arrays in Ruby?

Tags: arrays, ruby, compare

I'm looking for a method to compare two arrays, taking into account the position of their elements, and to create a new array based on that comparison.

For example:

```
arr_1      = [ "1", "1", "99", "1",  nil,  "",  "1",  ""]
arr_2      = ["99",  "", "99", nil,  nil,  "", "99", "1"]
arr_result = [ "1", "1", "99", "1", "99", "99", "1", "1"]
```

`arr_result` is created as following: If in the same position, one of the element from either array is `"1"`, the new array will have `"1"` in that position; otherwise `"99"`.

Is there any elegant method to achieve that?

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`zip`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.0.1/Array.html#zip-method) to combine the elements in a pair-wise manner:

```
arr_1.zip(arr_2)
#=> [["1", "99"], ["1", ""], ["99", "99"], ["1", nil], ...]
```

These pairs can then be [`map`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.0.1/Enumerable.html#map-method)-ed
to the desired output, e.g.:

```
arr_1.zip(arr_2).map { |pair| pair.include?("1") ? "1" : "99" }
#=> ["1", "1", "99", "1", "99", "99", "1", "1"]
```

`pair.include?("1")` checks whether the pair contains a `"1"`. If it does, its result is `"1"` and `"99"` otherwise. (using the [ternary operator](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.0.1/doc/syntax/control_expressions_rdoc.html#label-Ternary+if))

You could also check each value separately:

```
arr_1.zip(arr_2).map { |a, b| (a == "1" || b == "1") ? "1" : "99" }
#=> ["1", "1", "99", "1", "99", "99", "1", "1"]
```